# What exactly is my program "linking" with overall?

Tags: c++, linking

I have heard that my C++ programs "need to link with the C++ library/runtime". However, the C++ runtime is just the compiler inserting [stack operation code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) in to the image, or "boilerplate" code if you will. The C++ runtime is basically intrinsic to the program itself, so "linking the runtime" is a bit illogical. Linking a library makes more sense, especially since the C++ libraries are independent objects which would otherwise need resolvement with the source program itself, and [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29).

So I wondered, besides the C++ library, what else, or how do you know what you are linking with exactly? For example, if I'm supposedly linking with the C++ library, I also need to link with the OS-specific library and API as well, or at least a wrapper of some sort that will deal directly with it.

So the linker will, in effect, link the main program file with the C++ library with the OS-API/library? That doesn't sound particularly right.

Basically, the linker will link multiple libraries together(statically, in this example, at compile/link-time)?

Comment: It sounds like you have a general sense of what a linker does, as to what it's linking with really depends on what you call the linker with (or your toolchain calls it with for that matter). I'm no C++ person but I don't think anyone can say what your particular toolchain is linking without inspecting your configuration and it surely links different things for each thing you compile so I'm really not sure this is an answerable question.

Comment: That's the question ... the linker's work seems to be "hidden" a bit from the typical programmer. I _want_ to know what I am linking with, definitely. I was just asking, for clarification, to see the basis of this understanding.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix and Linux, you can see which libraries are linked with the [ldd](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ldd+1) command.  The output from an empty c++ program I made as a test was:

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xb77ba000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb76ae000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0xb7668000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb764c000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0xb749c000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77bb000)
```

`linux-gate` and `ld-linux` are treated specially by the linker.  The rest are all more or less regular libraries.  They are all open source, so you can see precisely what they do.  Search for "libstdc++ source" for example.

They basically contain implementations for anything that is too long to inline:  standard library containers, memory allocation, trigonometry, sockets, file handles, etc.  These implementations are highly specific to architecture and operating system.  They make calls into the kernel for the operating system they were compiled for.  I've had to implement several `libc` functions for a custom embedded operating system.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have totally misunderstood the concept of a runtime libray. 
The runtime is an executable, it does lots of work allocating storage, opening sysout, syserr etc and setting up various traps and signals **before** your main is called.

Thereafter it performs all your basic IO via fopen(), fread(), etc. calls, handles any memory management via "malloc()" and much much more.

I would stress again that the runtime is an executable. Implementation varies depending on the hardware and OS involved but it is usually some sort of shared executable like a windows ".dll" which is loaded only once and shared by all the c++ programs in the system.

Comment: I don't know what a runtime libray is, but any linked libraries are not technically program-scope or level runtime. The runtime is the C++ compiler's inserted operations in to the executable which, for the sake of the linker/file format, does vary from an ELF to a COFF, a MACH to a COM, etc. But a library's runtime is, yeah, working how you put it. Unfortunately, I would not go on a limb and say that the library's code, or "runtime" is actually the program's.

Comment: user93262 -- the C++ runtime is a separate executable. The "inserted operations" are instruction codes and calls within your generated object model. On windows for instance every C++ program will use a the "msvcp120.dll" or similar depending on the version of your compiler. These are distributed in a folder call MicrosoftVC120.CRT, the CRT here stands for C/cpp Run Time  -- If you think you already know the answer why bother asking someone who does?

Answer (score 1):

For any compiled language, the language specifies a run-time environment that you rely upon. For example in C and C++, you expect to be able to pass command-line arguments, that there will be standard output, standard error and standard input files. You expect execution to begin at main. The run-time library does all those things for you. It also does things that aren't obvious, such as setting up your program's memory structure or layout.

On each OS, it has to be tweeked a bit to provide that standard environment within the features / requirements of the particular operating system.

So, any time you are linking a program that will run under an OS, you'll have the run-time library linked. Separate to that you will have other libraries, such as the standard library for your language, which contains all those "normal" functions and classes you expect to see, plus any other libraries you need to use such database etc.

Comment: There's a difference between a runtime for a library, and the runtime for the executable's scope itself.

Answer (score 0):

What gets linked depends on what's in your program. Typically a program will be linked with the C runtime. If your C++ program uses STL, you may also get STL support, depending on which features you use.

You didn't say what platform you are using. Depending on the platform, you can use different tools to show what libraries your program is linked with. Program can also be linked statically or dynamically.

Comment: Terrible answer. This should not even be on my question.